# Does keras.tokenizer.text_to_sequence simply translate into number vectors, or something more?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

im currently trying to learn the ins and outs of keras.
in working with a dataset containing sentences, I m doing the following

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

max_features = 2000
tokens = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features)
tokens.fit_on_texts(list(X_train))
tokenized_train = tokens.texts_to_sequences(X_train) # Converting to ints
tokenized_test = tokens.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
```

Now, after doing this, i seem to have a vector for every word, but I am unsure om something, when i call tokens.text_to_sequences() is the word simply being converted integer, or is something more going on?
By "something more" i mean whether, keras is able to cluster words that are semantically related?

edit: if anyone knows what is going on behind the scenes (Word2Vec,GloVe or fastText) that would be really cool to know too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens.

When you first call `Tokenizer` with `num_words` and then, call `fit_on_texts` on it, then, from your text, the top `num_words` with highest frequency will be taken by it and then, a simple dictionary will be created in the format.

dict = {'topmost_word': 1,
        '2nd_topmost_word': 2,
         ...
        'num_wordsth_topmost_word: num_words
        }

Thus, only words are being converted into integers. No other magic happens here.

That something more about clustering happens in the `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` where the embedding are learning for each word. The embeddings you will get from here will be learned vectors and words of same class will be close here.

Comment: nice, so the first index will simply be the most common non-trivial word in the set?

And also just to be certain i understand, embedding happens during the training, where the vectors are being updated to better fit the clusterings?

Comment: yes. but, if you set oov_token in `Tokenizer`, then the second word will be the most common word.

Comment: And also just to be certain i understand, embedding happens during the training, where the vectors are being updated to better fit the clusterings?  thx alot

Comment: Embedding are fitted to better perform the task you are trying to achieve. Let's take example of IMDB movie review dataset, it has positive and negative reviews. Now, the words that belong to positive reviews will have embeddings that will be close to each other and vice-versa, words belonging to negative reviews will be close.

Comment: They are being fitted so they are able to better perform the task at hand.

Comment: ahh ok, nice thanks. if you dont feel like anwsering anymore, i totally understand :) 
but this happens pretraining right?

Comment: now, it does not happen pretraining. what you are talking about is when people get pretrained weights and then load those weights into their network like GLoVe from Stanford.

Comment: well strictly speaking keras-language. when i call embed() way before im calling model.train(), then embed() happens before my actual training of my model?

Comment: When you call model.train(), it takes your first batch and throws inside the neural network you designed i.e. the first layer, which is the first layers you define most of the time. So, embedding layer actually gets trained after you call model.train().

Comment: when you say "first batch" that is the non-embedded dictionary, coming from texts_to_sequences()?

Comment: training samples are in an array, their first batch I am talking about.

Comment: but if layers are embedded and clustered first after training of my actual model. Is'nt the training of that model rendered useless?

Comment: you sent the first batch through the whole network, you got some loss, now that loss will be backpropagated and the weights in the whole network will change. the embeddings are what they are as a consequence of the final output.